# Ошибка в коде Java c использованием DFS

Tags: java, ввод, dfs

при вводе данного кода выдает ошибку. В чем она заключается?

```
Compilation error
Main.java:9: error: ';' expected
            int sum+=DFS(i, i+1>n ? 1 : i+1);
```

Код следующий:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    
    class Main {
        void DFS(int sum) {       
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int n = in.nextInt();
            for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
            {
                int sum+=DFS(i, i+1>n ? 1 : i+1);
            }
            print(sum);
        }
    }
```

Comment: вас в этой строчке ничего не смущает? `int sum+=DFS(i, i+1>n ? 1 : i+1);` Например, заново объявленная переменная или вызов несуществующей функции

Comment: и как это можно пофиксить?